# XPath query to parse xml properties file

Tags: xml, xpath, properties

I have the following xml document:

```
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">  
<properties>  
    <comment>My Happy Configuration</comment>  
    <entry key="HappyKey">Happy Key</entry>  
    <entry key="SadKey">Sad Key</entry>  
    <entry key="AngryKey">Angry Key</entry>  
    <entry key="ConfusedKey">Confused Key</entry>  
    ...
</properties>
```

I am executing the following xpath query:

```
/properties/entry[@key='HappyKey']
```

I anticipate this to return HappyKey, however it returns nothing.

Comment: In what context are you using this xpath? Can you post the code that uses it? The xpath expression appears to be correct - tested [here](http://chris.photobooks.com/xml/default.htm) with your xml document.

Comment: Im running this from the context of InstallBuilder, I won't be able to verify this until tomorrow though

Comment: @Oded, there's an error on your page. The xml could not be executed correctly. You may want to fix it.

Comment: @Helen - That's not my page. The XML I put it was well formed, and I used the xpath provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for the value only then try:

```
/properties/entry[@key='HappyKey']/text()
```

Comment: XPath is a hosted language. So, to access the `entry` element string value, or the string value of all `entry` element's childs text nodes (this is what your expression means) is a matter of the host language.